# How do I keep custom cursor reset function from interfering with vim-template?

Tags: cursor-movement, autocmd

I have an autocommand function in my `.vimrc` that resets the cursor to where it was before I last closed the file. This function looks like this:

```
function! ResCur()
  if line("'\"") <= line("$")
    normal! g`"      
    return 1
  endif
endfunction                                                             
autocmd BufWinEnter * call ResCur()
```

I started using [vim-template](https://github.com/aperezdc/vim-template) which recognizes a `%HERE%` variable in the templates that sets the cursor location. My custom function overrides this capability. Is there a way to change my autocommand to only reset the cursor when a template is not loaded so the `%HERE%` variable still works when a template is loaded? If part of the solution involves using a different template plugin, I would be happy to hear that as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since this should only work for existing files, you'll want to use `BufRead` instead of `BufWinEnter`.  `vim-template` won't trigger `BufRead`.

If you really need `BufWinEnter` to be used to process modelines before calling your function, you can use `BufRead` to set a buffer variable:

```
autocmd BufRead * let b:not_new = 1
```

And check if the variable exists before moving the cursor.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the [vim-template source](https://github.com/aperezdc/vim-template/blob/master/plugin/templates.vim#L394), it checks for the existence of `%HERE%` when jumping, you could do the same:

```
function! ResCur()
  if search("%HERE%", "n")
    return
  endif

  if line("'\"") <= line("$")
    normal! g`"      
    return 1
  endif
endfunction                                                             
autocmd BufWinEnter * call ResCur()
```

The `n` flag means `do not move the cursor on search` and the function return the line number, you can check its existence before moving.

This should be fine (I've not tested though, as I don't have the plugin installed).

Comment: I attempted this and it wasn't reliable. The best programmatic way I found was using `histget('search' -1) == '%HERE%'` then `histdel(search, -1)` if found. But that seemed like overkill since `BufRead` appeared to be adequate.

Comment: Make sense, it was just a wild guess without having the plugin :3

Comment: It was definitely a good guess! The problem is the plugin uses `BufNewFile` which runs before `BufWinEnter`.  If `BufWinEnter` is really needed, a second autocmd can't be avoided.